# Installing uWSGI with asyncio support on MAC OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: macos, uwsgi, osx-yosemite, python-asyncio, greenlets

I've tried to build **uWSGI** with **asyncio** support following the [uWSGI documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/asyncio.html). I'm using **OS X 10.10 Yosemite** with Virtualenv.

First I've used the command `python3-config --include` to get my python3 include path. But when I try to build uWSGI + Asyncio with the following command:

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m" UWSGI_PROFILE="asyncio" pip install uwsgi
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
plugins/greenlet/greenlet.c:2:10: fatal error: 'greenlet/greenlet.h' file not found

#include <greenlet/greenlet.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Has anyone run into this issue before? I've tried tu install **Greenlet** first using *pip* in my virtualenv and in my global python instalation but I'm still getting `'greenlet/greenlet.h' file not found`. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed! Looks like the first thing needed was installing greenlet on the global python3.4 interpreter:

```
pip3 install greenlet
```

and then run the uWSGI + Asyncio installation on virtualenv as follows:

```
CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/python3.4m" UWSGI_PROFILE="asyncio" pip install uwsgi
```

If someone needs more detail, I've created a small tutorial:

- [How to install uWSGI + Asyncio on Mac (OS X 10.10 Yosemite)](http://www.developerfiles.com/installing-uwsgi-with-asyncio-on-mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite/)